# Selecting items from a list with repeated elements

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have L = {a, a, b, b, c}, how can we find the amount of lists with 3 elements, disregarding order?

Computing all possibilities, manually, results in {a, a, b} {a, b, b} {a, a, c} {b, b, c} {a, b c}, so 5 lists. Thing is, I couldn't manage to find this answer with basic combinatoral analysis, which is unpleasant as I wish to expand this example to larger initial lists, and with more repetitions, such as L = {a, a, a, a, b, b, c, d, d, d}.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a different structure to that of sets to phrase your question, since the sets $\{a,a,b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ are equal, and thus $\{a,a,b\}$ has only 2 elements, and there is only one subset of the set in question with 3 elements, and it is the set itself, $\{a,b,c\}$

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to edit the post! As english isn't my first language, I choose the wrong wording for this problem.

Comment: The answer to your original example is the number of solutions in the nonnegative integers of the equation $x_a + x_b + x_c = 3$, subject to the restrictions $x_1 \leq 2$, $x_2 \leq 2$, $x_3 \leq 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for your elegant solution!